# How to plot high oscillatory function with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I tried to plot sin(100x) and similar high frequency sinx plot; but the plot doesn't look like that. Can someone help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
                \addplot {sin(10*deg(x))}; 
                \addplot {sin(25*deg(x))};
                \addplot {sin(50*deg(x))};
                \legend{$\sin(10x)$,$\sin(25x)$,$\sin(50x)$}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
                \addplot {sin(100*deg(x))}; 
                \addplot {sin(150*deg(x))};
                \addplot {sin(200*deg(x))};
                \legend{$\sin(100x)$,$\sin(150x)$,$\sin(200x)$}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{lajsdfls}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: For each of your plots, a coordinate is calculated every *x* units. These coordinates are then connected by straight lines. As for sin(150*x*), the values just happen to be in such a way that the coordinates form a straight line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: That's called *aliasing* - look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing and scroll to "complex sinusoid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Main defferences between your MWE an suggested solution below are marked in code by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    trig format=rad,    % <---
    domain=0:1,         % <---
    samples=501,        % <---
    no marks,           % <---
% 
    legend style={font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west}}
    ]           
\addplot {sin(10*x};
\addplot {sin(25*x)};
\addplot {sin(50*x)};

\legend{$\sin(10x)$,$\sin(25x)$,$\sin(50x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```